# Safari browser always sees an update to unchanged service worker

Tags: javascript, vue.js, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

I've built a VueJS PWA and used `register-service-worker` to manage a service worker. I've built the app so when a new route is visited, it manually checks for an update to the service worker. If there is an update, it displays an alert to the user to refresh.

However, I'm experiencing a problem in Safari (both MacOS and iOS). While the update code works correctly, when visiting the web app in Safari it appears to constantly trigger the "update available" alert on every route change and refreshing doesn't seem to resolve the problem. It's as if Service Worker isn't get updated locally even though the web app shows the latest changes.

This is the code that manually checks on route changes:

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`).then(reg => {
        // check for updates to the service working on change of route
        reg.update();
    });
});
```

My `registerServiceWorker.js` then has then within the `updated` part which fires a custom event then there is an update to the service worker that the app can listen for:

```js
/* eslint-disable no-console */

import { register } from 'register-service-worker'

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
    ready () {
      console.log(
        'App is being served from cache by a service worker.\n' 
      )
    },
    registered () {
      console.log('Service worker has been registered.')
    },
    cached () {
      console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.')
    },
    updatefound () {
      console.log('New content is downloading.')
    },
    updated (registration) {
        console.log('New content is available; please refresh.')
        document.dispatchEvent(
            new CustomEvent('swUpdated', { detail: registration })
        )
    },
    offline () {
      console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.')
    },
    error (error) {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error)
    }
  })
}
```

My vue app then listens for "swUpdated" and displays alert to the user to refresh their browser if there is a new service worker.

```js
...
document.addEventListener('swUpdated', this.updateAvailable, { once: true })
...
updateAvailable(event) {

   this.registration = event.detail
   this.showReloadDialog = true
},
...
```

Comment: Are you using firebase hosting as well? Just following a hunch

Comment: @HimanshuPant I struggling with the same issue but without firebase.